# how to create simple array(without key) by putting available values in php

Tags: php

I have values like

```
"34,37"
```

and I want to create array using this values, array like

```
array('34','37')
```

How to create such array if I have values.

Comment: you should use `preg_split()` function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**hope this will help you :**

you can use `explode` function if you have values as string;

```
  $string = '34,37';
  $data = explode(',',$string):
  print_r($data); /*output array*/
```

for more : http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
$val = "34,37"
$val = explode(',', $val);
print_r($val);
```

output of above array:

```
Array
(
  [0] => 34,
  [1] => 37
)
```

Answer (score 1):

As per my comment, you should use `preg_split` function. for more details about `preg_split` function please read [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) and also you can use `explode` function [Explode function PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

```
<?php
      $string = '34,37';
      $keywords = preg_split("/[\s,]+/", $string);
      //OR $keywords = preg_split("/,/", $string); separated by comma only
      print_r($keywords);
```

you can check your desired [Output here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7daa18af4ed234f203f56ae324b4afc5205587ff)

Answer (score 1):

If you have a string like this:

```
$str = "1,2,3,4,5,6";
```

And you want to convert it into array, just use `explode()`

```
$myArray = explode(',', $str);
var_dump($myArray);
```

Have a look [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) for more information